# What's different between char and char [1]?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, char, string-literals

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Student {
  int id;
  char name[10];
  char sex;
  int grade;
};

int main() {
  struct Student std;
  std.id = 1;
  strcpy(std.name, "Kevin");
  std.sex="M";
  std.grade = 2;
  printf("%d %s %s %d\n", std.id, std.name, std.sex, std.grade);
}
```

In this code, got error on allocating a sex character in std variable.
I thought 'M' is only one character so that It will works in structure like normal variable did.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Student {
  int id;
  char name[10];
  char sex[1];
  int grade;
};

int main() {
  struct Student std;
  std.id = 1;
  strcpy(std.name, "Kevin");
  strcpy(std.sex, "M");
  std.grade = 2;
  printf("%d %s %s %d\n", std.id, std.name, std.sex, std.grade);
}
```

I fixed code like this then it works.

So my question is,

1. What's different between char and char [1] in memory perspection?
2. Why char sex doesn't work in structure?

I seached but can't find answer. Help me!

Comment: `'M'` is a character, `"M"` is a string of a single character and terminated with a 0 value (i.e. it's 2 chars). If you handle `char` use `'`, if you want "strings" (i.e. multiple chars) use `"`.

Comment: `"M"` is a string. A constant pointer to a place in memory containing chars `'M'` and `'\0'`. `'M'` is a char. That is an integer. See it as an alias to 77. `std.sex='M'` or `std.sex=77` or `std.sex=0x4d` or `std.sex=0115` are 4 ways to say the exact same thing. `char` in C is the name of a 8 bit integer type. `'M'` is an integer (77). `char *` is a pointer to such an integer (or to a sequence of integers). And `"M"` is a constant `char *` pointing, as I said, to a place in memory where you can find bytes 77 and 0 aka `'M'` and `'\0'`.

Comment: None of your two codes are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` is a scalar type while `char[1]` is an array type with one element.
`"M"` is a string literal that has character array type `char[2]` and in memory is stored like `{ 'M', '\0' }`.

You can check that using this call of `printf`

```
printf( "sizeof( \"M\" ) = %zu\n", sizeof( "M" ) );
```

In this statement

```
std.sex="M";
```

you are trying to assign the array (string literal) `"M"` to the scalar object `std::sex` of the type `char`. In this assignment the character array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. In fact you have

```
std.sex = &"M"[0];
```

while you need to write at least like

```
std.sex = "M"[0];
```

though instead of the string literal it will be simpler and clear to use an integer character constant like

```
std.sex = 'M';
```

Correspondingly in the call of `printf` you shall use conversion specifier `c` instead of `s` to output a single character

```
printf("%d %s %c %d\n", std.id, std.name, std.sex, std.grade);
              ^^
```

In the second program as the data member `sex` is declared as an array with one element

```
char sex[1];
```

then this call of `strcpy`

```
strcpy(std.sex, "M");
```

writes into memory outside the array `sex` because as pointed out above the string literal `"M"` has two elements. As a result the second program is also invalid. It seems it works only due to the alignment of the data member `int grade;` that is the compiler inserts additional bytes after the data member `sex` to provide the alignment.

You could declare the character array like

```
char sex[2];
```

though as you are going to use only one character then it will be enough to declare the data member `sex` as

```
char sex;
```

and use it as shown above in the comments for the first program.

Pay attention to that you could initialize the object of the structure type in its declaration the following way

```
struct Student std = 
{
    .id = 1, .name = "Kevin", .sex = 'M', .grade = 2
};
```

or

```
struct Student std = 
{
    1, "Kevin", 'M', 2
};
```